# Find quantile for whole dataframe

Tags: r

I want to find the quantile of my whole df.

```
a <- rbind(5, 10, 1.5)
b <- rbind(1.5, 6.7, 7)
c <- rbind(3.5, 10.2, 5)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
> quantile(df)
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `unlist` and convert to `vector` as according to `?quantile` documentation the input `x` is

> x - numeric vector whose sample quantiles are wanted, or an object of a class for which a method has been defined (see also ‘details’). NA and NaN values are not allowed in numeric vectors unless na.rm is TRUE.

Thus, `unlist` to create a `vector` and get the `quantile` for the whole data

```
quantile(unlist(df))
#  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
# 1.5  3.5  5.0  7.0 10.2
```